# Basic Rust code compiles and runs but CLion gives move error

Tags: rust, clion, intellij-rust

The following function:

```rust
fn double(n: u32) -> u32 {
    n + n
}
```

gives the following error:

[image: "Use of moved value"]

while it compiles and runs just fine with no warnings.

I'm using the latest release of both CLion and the IntelliJ-Rust plugin along with the latest rustc nightly (clippy etc all updated too).

Comment: IntelliJ's "helpful" editor features always have some trouble I notice flagging things that aren't problems - not just for Rust, but Java and JS too.

Comment: Heh.. I think they only need to run IntelliJ to see these problems.

Comment: BTW, sometimes `File > Invalidate Caches...` can make these bad indicators in the editor go away. In fact, I remember the last time I used IntelliJ I was seeing this same error - and I don't use CLion.. Intellij was flagging all the uses of primitive type copies - and they should be fine.

Comment: I changed this error to `weak warning`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a currently unresolved issue in the IntelliJ-Rust plugin.

See the related issue [here](https://github.com/intellij-rust/intellij-rust/issues/3987).

I'll be switching to vscode using rls.

Comment: check out rust-analyzer on the way~